# In Visual Studio, how can I search for data in a datagridView that was populated with a CSV file?

Tags: c#

I am using C# and Visual Studio 2017 and I am a bit new to it. I created a datagridview that was populated with a CSV file and I can create and import data from such files to my datagridview but I want to add a search option, either using the project number of project name. The way I currently have it set up by watching tutorial and reading is like this to import and populate the table:

```
using (OpenFileDialog importData = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter="CSV|*.csv", ValidateNames = true })

{
    if (importData.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var import = new StreamReader(new FileStream(importData.FileName, FileMode.Open));

        var csv = new CsvReader(import);
        cCIProjectsBindingSource.DataSource =csv.GetRecords<CCI_Projects>();
```

The reason I am doing it like this without using SQL is because it is for a small company that is currently working only with excel and dont want to pay for a database service just yet. If this is an inefficient way to do this please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You must conduct the search line-by-line and using the Column you expect to have the desired value.

Something like:

```
    try
    {
        foreach (MyLine as DataGridViewRow in __YourDataGridView.Rows)
        {
            CurrentValueN = MyLine.Cells(1).Value

            // (or you can utilize named cells like)

            CurrentValueN = MyLine.Cells("FirstColumn").Value
        }
    catch (exception ex)
    { }
```

It's important to mention that FIRSTCOLUMN is NOT the field name but the ColumnName in the Datagridview properties.

Comment: Thank you Ben!  :)

Comment: Also I am curious, I was using this before and did not work very well. Anybody knows if this is the proper way to use it?

Comment: string searchedText = SearchAllProjectsBox.Text;
            
 var matchedRows = this.dataGridView1.Rows
                 .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                 .Select(r => r.Cells["ProjectName"].Value)
                 .Where(v => v != null && v.ToString() == searchedText)
                 .ToList();